# How to change parent group?

Tags: user-groups

How can I see and edit the Group Parent setting for an existing User Group?

When a user group is created, you set the Group Title and Group Parent. Going to the Edit Group page lets me change the title but there is nothing relating to the Group Parent.

Joomla 3.8.12

Comment: Do you have Super Admin rights? If not, what rights do you have?  We are trying to determine if you _can't_ do this task within the Administrator interface, or if you merely didn't know where to look.  If you aren't sure, you might share a screenshot with us.

Comment: Yes, I have Super Admin.  I thought I knew where to look but was not seeing it there.  It turns out that I was looking in the right place ... but I was looking at Public which is special in that it does not have a parent group and therefore does not show on the Edit Group page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that you have admin access then you can follow the steps below

In the site admin area and go to the Users menu
Select the Groups menu item

[image]

User group select group menu

Find the group you want to move to a different parent and click on it to open it

[image]

Select the group

[image]

Change the group title if required.

Change the parent by selecting the down arrow drop down next to the existing group parent.

[image]

Save and close and review new parent location

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was doing, except that I was looking at the Public group.  Since that is the top of the tree it doesn't have a parent and so there is no option to edit - which makes sense.  The option does appear for me on the other groups as in your screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this in the database. User_group_map is the table I think. Use PHPMyAdmin to find the information and edit it.

Comment: It is easier and less error-prone to simply use the Administrator interface rather than manually manipulating the database.

Comment: But he said once he has created the group he can no longer access the parent. I haven't checked but if that is the case my answer is the only possiblity.